# Add Gallery images dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I've done Gallery of images displayed on emulator by static(i.e images from `drawable` folder).Now i need to add some images into the list of gallery, dynamically from the local path(for **ex.from E:/anim.jpeg** like that).How can i do that?Thanks..

My gallery code is shown below..

```
public class GalleryAct extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;
private ImageView imgView;

private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7,
        R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    
    imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);

     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the file path where the image is saved.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives path of sdcard.

```
  File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test2.png");


 BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

 imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If your image is too big size than bitmap will give error so for that you have to write below code to resize image. Pass the file in below function

```
 Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f1);
 imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

 private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi..I checked with above answer.Thanks.But it take images internally from a path and shown the images to viewers.But.. i have to create a browse button.when user clicks that button on emulator.a new popup window should open.it will show list of images in drawble folder of the same application.then i've to choose one image from that.it should b added into gallery list to display.(i.e like file attaching on mails).Is it possible?Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can try make your image array a dynamic list, ex: ArrayList. Upon the arrival of new item, add it to the list, and call notifyDataSetChanged() (method of the adapter), and your gallery list will be refreshed.

Depends on your case, I found that it is better to use AsyncTask here to update the list, and call notifyDataSetChanged.

The adapter class would looks similarly to this

```
public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return bitmapList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return bitmapList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return bitmapList.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        // imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmapList.get(position));

        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any errors, I am way to depending on IDE.