# how to upload image from gallery into my application

Tags: android, image

I have used this code so that I can be upload an image from gallery into my application. But the problem is I get force to close error when my application try to open gallery.

Please help me because I don't know how to solve this error

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath; 
    private ImageView img;  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"SelectPicture"), SELECT_PICTURE);}});
          }    
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)

        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri); 
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);  
            }     
        }  }
                    public String getPath(Uri uri) {  
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);   
        cursor.moveToFirst();       
        return cursor.getString(column_index);}}
```

here ia my LogCat

```
06-04 14:41:06.236: D/AndroidRuntime(9655): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 14:41:06.236: D/AndroidRuntime(9655): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 14:41:07.906: D/AndroidRuntime(9655): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-04 14:41:08.396: D/dalvikvm(282): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 5% free 6243K/6531K, paused 13ms+5ms
06-04 14:41:08.418: W/ActivityManager(80): No content provider found for: 
06-04 14:41:08.497: W/ActivityManager(80): No content provider found for: 
06-04 14:41:08.546: D/PackageParser(80): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl881881834.tmp
06-04 14:41:08.776: I/PackageManager(80): Removing non-system package:imag.imo.isithombe
06-04 14:41:08.776: I/ActivityManager(80): Force stopping package imag.imo.isithombe uid=10045
06-04 14:41:08.776: I/Process(80): Sending signal. PID: 6434 SIG: 9
06-04 14:41:08.776: I/ActivityManager(80):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{409fd970 imag.imo.isithombe/.ImagggggggActivity}
06-04 14:41:08.901: I/WindowManager(80): WIN DEATH: Window{40faeaa8 imag.imo.isithombe/imag.imo.isithombe.ImagggggggActivity paused=true}
06-04 14:41:09.798: D/PackageManager(80): Scanning package imag.imo.isithombe
06-04 14:41:09.798: I/PackageManager(80): Package imag.imo.isithombe codePath changed from /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-2.apk to /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-04 14:41:09.819: I/PackageManager(80): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk
06-04 14:41:09.915: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk' ---
06-04 14:41:10.755: D/dalvikvm(9664): DexOpt: load 100ms, verify+opt 327ms
06-04 14:41:10.776: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk' (success) ---
06-04 14:41:10.785: W/PackageManager(80): Code path for pkg : imag.imo.isithombe changing from /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-2.apk to /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk
06-04 14:41:10.785: W/PackageManager(80): Resource path for pkg : imag.imo.isithombe changing from /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-2.apk to /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk
06-04 14:41:10.785: D/PackageManager(80):   Activities: imag.imo.isithombe.ImagggggggActivity
06-04 14:41:10.799: I/ActivityManager(80): Force stopping package imag.imo.isithombe uid=10045
06-04 14:41:11.455: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk@classes.dex
06-04 14:41:11.475: D/PackageManager(80): New package installed in /data/app/imag.imo.isithombe-1.apk
06-04 14:41:11.885: I/ActivityManager(80): Force stopping package imag.imo.isithombe uid=10045
06-04 14:41:12.635: D/dalvikvm(80): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 18% free 14554K/17735K, paused 9ms+42ms
06-04 14:41:12.985: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.providers.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:12.985: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.006: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:13.006: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.055: D/PackageManager(80): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
06-04 14:41:13.147: D/PackageManager(80): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
06-04 14:41:13.225: D/PackageManager(80): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
06-04 14:41:13.245: D/PackageManager(80): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
06-04 14:41:13.275: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.providers.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:13.275: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.625: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:13.657: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.665: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.providers.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:13.665: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.665: W/ActivityManager(80): Unable to launch app com.android.contacts/10000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:imag.imo.isithombe flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
06-04 14:41:13.680: W/ActivityManager(80): finishReceiver called but none active
06-04 14:41:13.725: W/RecognitionManagerService(80): no available voice recognition services found
06-04 14:41:14.046: D/dalvikvm(141): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2038K, 24% free 18162K/23687K, paused 7ms+19ms
06-04 14:41:14.275: I/Launcher(141): setLoadOnResume
06-04 14:41:15.685: D/dalvikvm(141): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1880K, 23% free 18301K/23687K, paused 12ms+23ms
06-04 14:41:17.347: D/dalvikvm(80): GC_EXPLICIT freed 286K, 19% free 14521K/17735K, paused 9ms+289ms
06-04 14:41:17.506: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@imag.imo.isithombe-2.apk@classes.dex
06-04 14:41:17.530: D/AndroidRuntime(9655): Shutting down VM
06-04 14:41:17.575: I/AndroidRuntime(9655): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-04 14:41:17.597: D/dalvikvm(9655): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 84% free 337K/2048K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-04 14:41:17.597: D/jdwp(9655): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-04 14:41:17.597: D/dalvikvm(9655): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-04 14:41:19.105: D/AndroidRuntime(9669): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 14:41:19.105: D/AndroidRuntime(9669): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 14:41:20.986: D/AndroidRuntime(9669): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-04 14:41:21.116: I/ActivityManager(80): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=imag.imo.isithombe/.ImagggggggActivity } from pid 9669
06-04 14:41:21.198: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21035
06-04 14:41:21.376: D/AndroidRuntime(9669): Shutting down VM
06-04 14:41:21.439: I/AndroidRuntime(9669): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-04 14:41:21.476: I/ActivityManager(80): Start proc imag.imo.isithombe for activity imag.imo.isithombe/.ImagggggggActivity: pid=9679 uid=10045 gids={}
06-04 14:41:21.496: D/dalvikvm(9669): GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 83% free 358K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-04 14:41:21.540: D/jdwp(9669): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-04 14:41:21.540: D/dalvikvm(9669): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-04 14:41:24.316: V/TLINE(9679): new: android.text.TextLine@406538d0
06-04 14:41:25.286: V/TLINE(9679): new: android.text.TextLine@406584d8
06-04 14:41:25.357: I/ActivityManager(80): Displayed imag.imo.isithombe/.ImagggggggActivity: +4s16ms
06-04 14:41:27.316: D/dalvikvm(324): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 6% free 6324K/6663K, paused 6ms+825ms
06-04 14:41:27.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4295): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-04 14:41:28.440: I/ActivityManager(80): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) } from pid 9679
06-04 14:41:28.445: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21040
06-04 14:41:28.795: I/ActivityManager(80): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=image/* flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery } from pid 9679
06-04 14:41:28.946: I/ActivityManager(80): Start proc com.android.gallery for activity com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: pid=9687 uid=10016 gids={1015, 1024, 1006, 2001, 3003}
06-04 14:41:30.685: D/AndroidRuntime(9687): Shutting down VM
06-04 14:41:30.685: W/dalvikvm(9687): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:204)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2339)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2546)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:219)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at com.android.camera.ImageGallery.onCreate(ImageGallery.java:113)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
06-04 14:41:30.746: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):     ... 11 more
06-04 14:41:30.775: W/ActivityManager(80):   Force finishing activity com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery
06-04 14:41:30.845: W/WindowManager(80): Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 21045
06-04 14:41:31.355: W/ActivityManager(80): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{409d6360 com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery}
06-04 14:41:34.515: I/Process(9687): Sending signal. PID: 9687 SIG: 9
06-04 14:41:34.565: I/ActivityManager(80): Process com.android.gallery (pid 9687) has died.
06-04 14:41:35.175: W/InputManagerService(80): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41028698
06-04 14:41:38.836: D/dalvikvm(402): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 5% free 6237K/6531K, paused 9ms+4ms
```

Comment: Use the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613668/add-gallery-images-dynamically-in-android

Comment: what is the android version you are testing in?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine
>   custom titles with other title features

I doubt you might have used

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

If so delete it.

Comment: where should i check for this?